# Is it possible to do a low-overhead file transfer knowing only the remote machine's IP address?

Tags: c#, ip, remote-access, file-transfer

I want to transfer a file from my computer to a remote computer in the field, but I only know that remote computer's IP address and am not able to install anything on it before the file transfer due to logistical reasons. Is there a file transfer protocol (preferably with a C# library) that makes this possible?

In the past I have done file transfers between computers using SCP, but that required installing OpenSSH on the remote computer before anything could be attempted. I would like to do this file transfer without having to install anything on the remote computer.

Comment: If you could send a file to any computer, knowing only its IP, without installing a receiving software, that would be a pretty huge security hole. I really doubt you will find a solution for this.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the case, but it never hurts to ask ;).

Comment: Couldn't agree more :)